# Angular 2 Dependencies Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am going to have a base class for my data services. I place common function like post, get, exception handler in the base class. Derived class just need to inherit the base class without Http or necessary stuff only used in the base class, the base class need to "resolve" it dependencies by itself.

```js
import { Injectable, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class DataServiceBase{
    private _injector: ReflectiveInjector;
    private get injector() : ReflectiveInjector{
        if(this._injector == null)
            this._injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([Http]);

        return this._injector;
    }

    private _http: Http;
    private get http(): Http{
        if(this._http == null)
            this._http = this.injector.get(Http);

        return this._http;
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleException(exception: any) {
        console.error(exception);
        return Observable.throw(exception.statusText);
    }

    protected post(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
        var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        var body = JSON.stringify(data);

        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleException);
    }

    protected get(url: string) : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleException);
    }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { TodoItem } from '../model/todoItem';

import { DataServiceBase } from './dataServiceBase';

@Injectable()
export class ValidationSampleService extends DataServiceBase{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    public getAllTodoItem(): Observable<any>{
        return this.get('/api/todo');
    }

    public updateToDoItem(item: any){
        return this.post('/api/todo/updateTodoItem', item);
    }
}
```

But I got an exception like "No provider for Http", can you advise which one I might miss?

Everything was working just fine if I inject services in constructor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the subclass doesn't have an explicit constructor, then the constructor of the superclass is used:

```
export class DataServiceBase{
  constructor(private http:Http){}
```

```
export class ValidationSampleService extends DataServiceBase{
    // constructor(){
    //    super();
    // }
```

See also

- [Inject Http manually in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243525/inject-http-manually-in-angular-2/39243599#39243599)
- [Access @angular/http Http Client from Plain Ol' TypeScript Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209998/access-angular-http-http-client-from-plain-ol-typescript-class/41210143#41210143)

Comment: the point is that a sub class needs to have the constructor to inject dependencies (just it needs), the sub class shouldn't care of Http used in the base class. This is not exactly what I want but your answer in another post does really help. it work just fine.

Comment: If the subclass has a constructor, the only option is to repeat all super constructor parameters in the subclass' constructor and pass them along using `super(...)` (or my other answer)